# e.offsetWidth returns wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my application I want to check if there is text-overflow(ellipsis). And for that I'm check `e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth` but they return equal value, means `offsetWidth` returns **wrong** value. Here is the my implementation:

**CSS**:

```
.less{
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.complete{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.collapse{
  color:blue;
  font-size:13px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.hideElement{
 display: none;
}

#seemore:after{
  content: " \000BB";
}
#seeless:before{
   content:"\000AB\ ";
}

#description {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id = "description">
    <div id="lessdescription" class="less"></div>
    <div id="seemore" class="collapse"></div>
    <div id="seeless" class="collapse hideElement"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function manageReportDescription() {
    var descriptionElement = document.getElementById("lessdescription");

    return descriptionElement.offsetWidth < descriptionElement.scrollWidth;
}
```

> I want to use pure JS properties (without relying on jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

You Javascript code is okay, the issue is because there is no text in your `div` so `offsetWidth` is equal to screen width and `scrollWidth` is also equal to screen width, so the comparison will return `false` because the two elements compared have the same value **screen width** , try adding some text in your `lessdescription` div

[image: When adding some text to the <code>div</code> the values change, and it return <code>true</code>]